# How do I remove .x.x.x.... and .y.y.y... from headings when I do a full join of multiple dataframes in R?

Tags: r

file1

| Country | Name | Race | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| .. | .. | .. | .. | .. | .. |

file2

| Country | Name | Race | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| .. | .. | .. | .. | .. | .. |

file3

| Country | Name | Race | G | H | I |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| .. | .. | .. | .. | .. | .. |

file4

| Country | Name | Race | J | K | L |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| .. | .. | .. | .. | .. | .. |

The above are a some .csv data frames that I assigned to a variable called `file.list`, and then used `lapply`. The purpose was to full join every data frame into a single one, as you can see by the code below.

`file.list= c(file1.csv, file2.csv, file3.csv, file4.csv)`

`df.list <- lapply(file.list, read.csv)`

`data <-df.list %>% reduce(full_join, by=c("Country", "Name", "Race"))`

data

| Country | Name | Race | A.x | B.x | C.x | D.y | E.y | F.y | G.x.x | H.x.x | I.x.x | J.y.y | K.y.y | L.y.y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| .. | .. | .. | .. | .. | .. | .. | .. | .. | .. | .. | .. | .. | .. | .. |

Although the full join works using the above code, the headers have a .x or .y added behind their names. This code also produced similar results:

`data<-power_full_join(df.list, by=c("Country", "Name", "Race"))`

How can I full join such that the headers retain their original names without the .x.x... and .y.y.. behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `plyr::join_all`

```
plyr::join_all(df_list, type = "full")
```

-output

```
  Country Name Race  A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I
1      Rf  wef  wed  1  1  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA
2      Ew eggw   qw  2  2  2 NA NA NA  4 11  8
3      Gw  wef  wed NA NA NA  3  5  7 NA NA NA
4      Wd eggw   qw NA NA NA  4  6  8 NA NA NA
5      Qp  wef  wed NA NA NA NA NA NA  3 10  7
```

#### data

```
df_list <- list(structure(list(Country = c("Rf", "Ew"), Name = c("wef", 
"eggw"), Race = c("wed", "qw"), A = 1:2, B = 1:2, C = 1:2), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L)), structure(list(Country = c("Gw", "Wd"), Name = c("wef", 
"eggw"), Race = c("wed", "qw"), D = 3:4, E = 5:6, F = 7:8), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(Country = c("Qp", 
"Ew"), Name = c("wef", "eggw"), Race = c("wed", "qw"), G = 3:4, 
    H = 10:11, I = 7:8), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1):

`full_join()` has an argument `suffix` which can be set to empty strings to achieve this.

```
data <-df.list %>% reduce(full_join, by=c("Country", "Name", "Race"), suffix=c("",""))
```

Answer (score 1):

A **base R** alternative joining a list of data frames.

##### Example

```
df_list
[[1]]
  Country Name Race A B C
1      Rf  wef  wed 1 1 1
2      Ew eggw   qw 2 2 2

[[2]]
  Country Name Race D E F
1      Gw  wef  wed 3 5 7
2      Wd eggw   qw 4 6 8

[[3]]
  Country Name Race G  H I
1      Qp  wef  wed 3 10 7
2      Ew eggw   qw 4 11 8
```

##### Function

```
join_list <- function(x, ax = T, ay = F){ 
  dff <- merge(x[[1]], x[[2]], all.x=ax, all.y=ay)
  if(length(x) > 2){
    for(i in seq_along(x)[3:length(x)]){ 
      dff <- merge(dff, x[[i]], all.x=ax, all.y=ay) 
  }}; dff }
```

use

```
join_list(df_list, ax=T, ay=T)
  Country Name Race  A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I
1      Ew eggw   qw  2  2  2 NA NA NA  4 11  8
2      Gw  wef  wed NA NA NA  3  5  7 NA NA NA
3      Qp  wef  wed NA NA NA NA NA NA  3 10  7
4      Rf  wef  wed  1  1  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA
5      Wd eggw   qw NA NA NA  4  6  8 NA NA NA
```

##### Data

```
df_list <- list(structure(list(Country = c("Rf", "Ew"), Name = c("wef",
"eggw"), Race = c("wed", "qw"), A = 1:2, B = 1:2, C = 1:2), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-2L)), structure(list(Country = c("Gw", "Wd"), Name = c("wef",
"eggw"), Race = c("wed", "qw"), D = 3:4, E = 5:6, F = 7:8), row.names = c(NA,
-2L), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(Country = c("Qp",
"Ew"), Name = c("wef", "eggw"), Race = c("wed", "qw"), G = 3:4,
    H = 10:11, I = 7:8), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame"))
```